# YouTrack - change default timepicker value

Tags: field, youtrack

In DataTime type Deadline field I want change default value only for time in time input. Not Deadline field value (this I want still have empty by default). How can I do this?

[image: field in time input]

Answer (score 2):

*I'm copying my reply from the support ticket you submitted.*

Unfortunately, there is no way to configure this field as you requested.

Comment: Thx for answer :)